# How to convert a .pdf file into a folder of images?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, pdf, convert

I have some .pdf files that I would like to convert to my preferred reading format of .cbr or .cbz  or, if this isn't directly possible, I need to extract all pages from the .pdf as images and then compress them into my format of choice.  I have only been able to save pages one at a time with Document Viewer.  Obviously, I'd like to do it a little quicker. I have tried pdfsam, pdf shuffler, and pdfmod all with no luck. I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK well, I did some more research and although tohuwawohu's method does work, I found it easier to use a program called [pdftoppm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftoppm) to achieve what I wanted done. Since I am pretty much a layperson when it comes to using command line apps, I will do my best to explain how I got this to work for me.

1. Navigate to the folder containing the .pdf you wish to edit and open a terminal there. I did this by using the sample command:

   ```
   cd ~/Documents/PDF
   ```
2. Let's say the file I want to edit is called Sample.pdf  What I want to do is use pdftoppm to create image files of each page of the .pdf.  Several formats can be chosen (see the man pages link above) but I prefer to use .png.  The basic command looks like this:

   ```
   pdftoppm -FORMAT FILENAME.pdf PREFIX
   ```

   or in the example above:

   ```
   pdftoppm -png Sample.pdf Sample
   ```

   This command creates an image file of each page in the same folder as the original .pdf file with names like Sample-01.png, Sample-02.png and so on.  I have tried it with the .png and .jpeg extensions successfully. .jpg is apparently not supported.
3. Then I just use [Archive Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/File%20Roller) by selecting all the newly-created image files, right-clicking, and choosing "Compress" from the context menu.  I then choose the archive format I prefer (in this case .cbz or Comic Book Zip) and create the new archive.
4. Now I have a shiny new .cbz file called Sample.cbz which I can then view with my [Comix](https://launchpad.net/comix) reader!

Hopefully what I have posted above makes enough sense that someone else can learn from it. If I need to change it in any way please let me know.

Comment: Very nice! It seems that `pdftoppm` is in fact easier to use than ImageMagick's `convert`.

Comment: yes it very helpful and easy. I just want to know. can add alpha prefix. Like prefix-a, prefix-b, prefix-c,        in this way

Comment: `pdftoppm` is extremely slow and uses all the RAM on my computer. `pdfimages -j` worked much better.

Comment: This doesn't work. All you get is a help message when using this syntax for `pdftoppm`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not very familiar with *.cbr / *.cbz, but it seems you'll have to combine two steps:

1. Convert PDF to Images
2. Compress them into a ZIP / RAR archive.

Regarding step 1, you could use [ImageMagick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ImageMagick)'s `convert` command. You can feed `convert` with a PDf comprising multiple pages, and `convert` will return each page as single graphics file. I've tested it with a text scanned at 400 dpi, and the following command resulted in nice single JPGEs:

```
$ convert -verbose -colorspace RGB -interlace none -density 400 -quality 100 yourPdfFile.pdf 00%d.jpeg
```

(credits regarding the `-quality` option: [this forum entry](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=12235))

As a result, you get `000.jpeg`, `001.jpeg` and so on. Just zip them into a `.cbz` file, and you're done.

You could even combine both steps by "concatenating" them:

```
$ convert -verbose -colorspace RGB -interlace none -density 400 -quality 100 yourPdfFile.pdf 00%d.jpg && zip -vm comic.cbz *.jpg
```

(make sure that there aren't any other JPEGs in your current working directory, since using the code above, zip will *move all* JPEGs into the cbz file)

Answer (score 4):

I have written a simple bash script for exactly this purpose, you will need poppler installed, so:

```
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils #ubuntu
brew install poppler # mac
```

Here is the bash script (save it as convert_to_cbz.sh):

```
filename="${1%.*}"
echo "Converting $filename to cbz"
mkdir "./$filename"
pdftoppm -jpeg "$1" "./$filename/000"
zip -r9 "${filename}.cbz" "./$filename" 
rm -rf "./$filename"
```

To use the bash script:

```
chmod +x convert_to_cbz.sh
./convert_to_cbz.sh "Nintendo Official Magazine 066 (OldGameMags).pdf"
```

Hopefully this will be useful for someone!

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. I had to change the script a bit though. `pdftoppm` used all my RAM and crashed my computer. Replacing the 4th line with `pdfimages -j "$1" "./$filename/000"
` did the trick. It works fine, it's fast, there doesn't seem to be any quality loss and the cbz is slightly smaller than the original pdf. `pdfimages` is also included in `poppler-utils`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using calibre to directly convert the .pdf to .cbr or .cbz.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for me using Calibre as a solution won't work.  I installed the program and I am sorry to say that it sticks out like a sore thumb on my desktop!  Also, I discovered using the pdftoppm command below is WAY faster than installing and configuring Calibre before converting.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, I would say that Calibre is ugly and slow,  but it does do the job. I'm glad you found a better solution, though :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the easiest way is using Acrobat Pro.

1. Open the PDf in Acrobat Pro.
2. Once the file is opened, go to `File` → `Export` → `Image` → `JPEG`, it will export each page as a single JPG.
3. Place all the JPGs in a folder
4. Zip the folder.
5. Manually change the extension at the end of the zipped file from *.zip* to *.cbz*

If you prefer a *CBR* file, rar the folder instead of zipping it, then change the extension from *.rar* to *.cbr*.